# app with combined frontend and backend not deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, deployment, angular7

I have a angular frontend and nodejs backend app. The issue I am having is when I deploy to Heroku, the build and compile succeeds but I think only the backend is being run on heroku when I click open app. I looked at multiple tutorials and resources on how to deploy an angular and nodejs app on heroku and followed all the instructions but am unable to successfully get the full web app(both angular frontend and nodejs backend to Heroku.

the output I get when navigating to the app from the heroku url is:

```
{"message":"Invalid Token"}
```

my package.json is :

```
{
  "name": "eserver",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "main": "server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod",
    "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli @angular/compiler-cli 
typescript",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "~7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.3",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.42",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "0.0.4",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^7.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "pusher-js": "^4.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.7",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.29",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "pusher": "^2.2.0",
    "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.5.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

my server.js is:

```
require('rootpath')();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('./eserver-backend/_helpers/jwt');
const errorHandler = require('./eserver-backend/_helpers/error- handler');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use(jwt());

// api routes
app.use('/users', require('./eserver- 
backend/users/users.controller'));
app.use('/categories', require('./eserver- 
backend/categories/categories.controller'));
app.use('/items', require('./eserver- 
backend/items/items.controller'));
app.use('/tableOrder', require('./eserver- 
backend/tableOrder/tableOrder.controller'));
app.use('/orders', require('./eserver- 
backend/order/order.controller'));
// global error handler
app.use(errorHandler);

// start server
const port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (process.env.PORT || 80) : 4000;
const server = app.listen(port, function () {
console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

my procfile is:

```
web: node server.js
```

my file structure is:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8nu9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the server.js fixed the issue 
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/angular-registration-login-example'));

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/dist/angular-registration-login-example/index.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js app should serve the static files in dist folder which were built with `ng build`

Add the following code in your server.js file.

```
// Run the app by serving the static files
// in the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

// For all GET requests, send back index.html
// so that PathLocationStrategy can be used
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: I added that to the server.js but still no difference

Comment: Do you see `Server listening on port` on console of heroku?

Comment: I think it's because of `app.use(jwt());`. jwt token was applied not only to the API routes but also to the front-end routes. Why don't you try to remove that line to see if the app works without it?

Comment: nevermind i see this in the herokuj console                             
     .           DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
2019-06-18T02:38:30.374897+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening on port 19736
2019-06-18T02:38:30.425132+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.

Comment: when i remove app.use(jwt()); i get {"message":"path is not defined"}

Comment: Will you try `app.get('/', function (req, res) {  res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'))});`?

Comment: i dont see a dist folder in my angular project

Comment: `ng build --prod` will generate dist folder

Comment: I imported path that should fix it i am waiting for the build now

Comment: You can try `npm run heroku-postbuild && npm run main` on your local to test it.

Comment: @Samuel now i am getting {"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/index.html'"}

Comment: You might be missing `/`. It should be `/dist/index.html`. :)

Comment: @Samuel i logged into heroku bash and found the correct file name and fixed it but the api calls wont work. is there an issue with the port or baseurl? did i miss something in the server.js or backend to listen or send api requests to the correct port. Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: Where did you write `app.get('/',...)`? It should be written after defining all the routes, so on your code base it should be put after `app.use('/orders', require('./eserver- 
backend/order/order.controller'));`

Comment: @Samuel if I do that then the app does not run. Are you sure my configuration of the port is right because each time I run it I see the server listening at a different port.