# I uploaded my frontend and backend app to Heroku but I cannot use jwt()

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, express-jwt, jwt

I uploaded my nodejs backend and angular frontend project to heroku and in order to get it working, I had to remove the app.use(jwt()); in order for the deployment to work. The issue is I want jwt to be used in the app. Once removed, I get the following message

```
 {"message":"Invalid Token"}
```

I think it is because the backend is requiring the static files to have a jwt token. How can I add jwt without breaking the app on heroku. The code can be found here
[app with combined frontend and backend not deploying to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640486/app-with-combined-frontend-and-backend-not-deploying-to-heroku/56658845#56658845)

the only difference in that code there is I added the get route in the comment and commented out the app.use(jwt());

Comment: what was the error message when using app.use(jwt()) in deployment? What version of node, express, angular, jwt package, etc. are you using? Could be outdated packages, in which case, you will need to update to current version. This can be caused due to realized high security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @pbordeaux I don't get an error, I get the following message {"message":"Invalid Token"}. I think its denying the frontend access because it does not have a jwt instead of navigating to the login screen. node version v10.9.0, npm version 6.9.0, Express version 4.17.0, jwt version 5.3.1, angular version 7.3.7.

Comment: I have not done express / node in a while, but is there not a failure redirect to specify? it seems like your app is not being served before the auth is being included, possibly? sorry i am a bit out of practice with this

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/app-name')); before the app.use(jwt());